# How can I wrap words but not wrap by whitespace with CSS?

Tags: html, css

With the following markup, is it possible (and how) to achieve a wrapping like shown in the preview?

**Markup**

```
<div class="filled-box">
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <p>I am just a text with some words, that want to fill the entire space</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.filled-box {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.filled-box h2,
.filled-box p {
  display: inline;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

**Preview**

```
Hi there I am
just a text w
ith some word
s, that want 
to fill the e
ntire space
```

If there is a solution it of course may use CSS3 Syntax.

Comment: Hi there is inside h2 tag which is a block element. So, I am is always going to be bellow Hi there

Comment: Did you notice `display: inline;`? An h2 element is just per default a block-element, but you can tell it to behave like an inline element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`word-break: break-all;`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp) is what you are looking for probably. Devil is in the details.

Your initial markup has an `h2` tag with a `p` tag and but your preview shows that they are all inline. `h2`and `p` tags are not inline elements.

And thus, making them `display: inline` is not the ideal thing to do, instead use inline elements, like `span` and others.

Another thing to notice here is that `word-break: break-all;` doesn't works properly on your inline elements. Just use the tags what they were made for and tweak the values according to our prefs.

```css
.filled-box {
  width: 85px;
  position: absolute;
}

.filled-box p span{
  word-break: break-all;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.filled-box p {
  word-break: break-all;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="filled-box">
  
  <p><span>Hi there</span> I am just a text with some words, that want to fill the entire space</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use word break property of css. Simply add

```
word-break: break-all;
```

It will automatically fill up the entire width and wrap the overflown text.

Also, replace the h2 tag as it is a block element

Comment: No, seems that `word-wrap` has been renamed to `overflow-wrap`, which as you can see I already used. And your solution doesn't solve the problem, that lines are wrapped at whitespaces.

Comment: Sorry i meant word-break, and not word-wrap. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

make the h2 float and inherit font-size :

```css
.filled-box {
  width: 85px;
  position: absolute;
  word-break: break-all;
  font-size: 16px;/* or whatever */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.filled-box * {
  margin: 0;/*reset*/
}

.filled-box h2 {
  float: left;
  font-size: inherit;
  padding-right: 0.2em;
  font-weight: normal; /*whatever*/ 
  color:rgb(51, 170, 255) /* whatever*/
}
```

```html
<div class="filled-box">
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <p>I am just a text with some words, that want to fill the entire space</p>
</div>
```

or use `display:contents`, but **not supported everywhere** unfortunatelly here:

```css
.filled-box {
  width: 85px;
  position: absolute;
  word-break: break-all;
  font-size: 16px;/* or whatever */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.filled-box * {  
  display:contents;
}

.filled-box h2 {
  font-size: inherit;
  padding-right: 0.2em;
  font-weight: normal; /*whatever*/ 
  color:rgb(51, 170, 255) /* whatever*/
}
```

```html
<div class="filled-box">
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <p>I am just a text with some words, that want to fill the entire space</p>
</div>
```

---

**The `display` value to used should be `run-in` supported once in Chrome :**

```css
.filled-box {
  width: 85px;
  position: absolute;
  word-break: break-all;
  font-size: 16px;
  /* or whatever */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.filled-box * {
  margin: 0/* reset*/
}

.filled-box h2 {
  display: run-in;
  font-size: inherit;
  padding-right: 0.2em;
  font-weight: normal;
  /*whatever*/
  color: rgb(51, 170, 255)/* whatever*/
}
```

```html
<div class="filled-box">
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <p>I am just a text with some words, that want to fill the entire space</p>
</div>
```

But it just doesn't work for many reason, see: https://css-tricks.com/run-in/